# Selecting Node with specific text that have a quote in them

Tags: python, xml, string, xpath, file-io

I have an XML document where i am using xpath to find specific nodes using the text.

For example the product that i am trying to find is the following product node in a file that has many product nodes.

```
<product>
    <code>10023</code>
    <name>
        <value language="en_US">There's Pippins and Cheese to Come</value>
        <value language="en_CA">There's Pippins and Cheese to Come</value>
    </name>
</product>
```

I am using the xpath query

```
node = self.productDoc.xpath("/product[name/value[text() = '{0}']]".format(self.Title))
```

where `productDoc = etree.parse(FileLocation)` from the Lxml module

My question is: when i try to select node with the xpath path provided above, i get invalid Predicate. 
I believe the problem is the single quote in the "There's Pippins and Cheese to Come" text
which is messing with the xpath path. 
How do I overcome this?

Comment: Have you tried it without the apos (single quote) in the data. TThis would be diagnostic for this error. What is {0} doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single quote is causing the problem, you need to escape it somehow in your xpath or use double quotes, this should work instead

```
node = self.productDoc.xpath("/product[name/value[text() = \"{0}\"]]".format(self.Title))
```